# What could be causing this packet loss on my broadband cable connection?

Tags: home-networking, isp, broadband, packet-loss

My home internet has been unreliable for the past month and so far my ISP has been at a loss to figure out why, so I want to make sure I've ruled out all possible causes on my end.

I have a 150/15 cable internet connection which I get through a local ISP who resells from a larger ISP that owns the infrastructure. For the past month or so, my connection seems to work fine for a few seconds, then it drops all packets for a few seconds, then works fine again for a bit. This results in streaming issues, web pages failing to load, etc. Working from home right now is next-to-impossible because my RDP connection freezes several times per minute and anything I try to type ends up with either missing or repeating characters.

This is an example of a ping test:

```
Pinging google.ca [172.217.0.227] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=515ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=523ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=513ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=519ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.0.227: bytes=32 time=519ms TTL=56
```

That's with the computer plugged directly into the modem, with no router or switch in-between. The ISP has run tests and there doesn't seem to be noise on my line, they say my signal is good.

Things I've tried:

- Running tests from different computers
- Replacing the modem with a new one the ISP sent me
- Unplugging the modem from the surge protector and plugging it directly into the wall (my ISP thought it was a power issue)
- Unplugging other devices in my house, and even turning off the breakers on all electrical circuits except the one with the modem plugged in
- Replacing the run of coax cable running through my house from the ISP's drop-point to my modem

I haven't noticed a difference with any of the things I've tried, and I haven't noticed a difference at different times of day (though I can mostly only do testing in the evenings, so this is hard to confirm).

Does anyone have any other tests I can run that might point to or rule out a problem on my end?

EDIT:
Here is traceroute data that I took at the same time as I did the ping tests. When I get home tonight I'll do more testing based on everyone's suggestions.

```
Tracing route to google.ca [172.217.164.227]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    14 ms    14 ms    16 ms  {MyIp}
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    25 ms    14 ms    21 ms  ae3-118-agg01-tor.teksavvy.com [104.195.128.69] 
  4    17 ms    16 ms    22 ms  ae4-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.94] 
  5    15 ms     *      518 ms  72.14.212.134 
  6    19 ms    16 ms     *     74.125.244.145 
  7    16 ms    14 ms    14 ms  216.239.41.247 
  8   516 ms    18 ms     *     yyz12s05-in-f3.1e100.net [172.217.164.227] 
  9     *      520 ms    28 ms  yyz12s05-in-f3.1e100.net [172.217.164.227] 

Trace complete.

Tracing route to one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *      518 ms    21 ms  {MyIp} 
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *      517 ms     *     ae2-218-agg01-tor2.teksavvy.com [104.195.128.213] 
  4     *      548 ms     *     ae10-0-bdr01-tor2.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.92] 
  5    17 ms    37 ms    16 ms  ae12-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.10] 
  6    20 ms    19 ms    30 ms  198.32.181.56 
  7    17 ms     *      512 ms  one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1] 

Trace complete.

Tracing route to reddit.com [151.101.1.140]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    19 ms    17 ms    17 ms  {MyIp} 
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3   581 ms    18 ms   528 ms  ae2-218-agg01-tor2.teksavvy.com [104.195.128.213] 
  4    15 ms    29 ms    23 ms  ae1-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.13] 
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6   518 ms    15 ms    17 ms  151.101.1.140 

Trace complete.
```

It doesn't appear to fail at any specific jump, so maybe it's just losing packets during the traceroute.

Comment: Try a traceroute, then ping nodes between you & them to see if you can figure out where it's dropping. If it's in the first couple of nodes, then yell at your ISP to come out & physically measure the line, see if it needs an attenuator adding or removing - though they ought to be able to partially check that from their end, if you can get elevated support, not the 'QA-sheet-reader' who first answers the phone.

Comment: This sounds like a common bad line scenario. You've done your job, replacing your line from your home to the ISP drop point, and replacing equipment. Have they came out with their equipment and ran a line test from their drop point to the ISP, or tried replacing their drop? If not, they're bad at doing their job.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a great idea pinging each node in the traceroute, I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: @DrZoo Yeah, they came out and tried the line with their test equipment, and they say it's fine.

Comment: When they tested the line, did they test from the drop to your home, or towards the ISP? Sometimes these cable issues are not on the customer premises.

Comment: @DrZoo He unplugged the cable connection to my modem and plugged into that, so I believe he would have been testing from my end to the ISP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have tried, I immediately think bad line. You have ruled out device issues, as well as any variable in between the device and the modem. So unless every single device you have are all experiencing the same flaw, then this seems to be an issue directly with either your line or the ISP's routing of your traffic. As a quick check for consistency, could you try pinging cloudflares DNS 1.1.1.1? If it is the same, then I believe another call is warranted to the ISP, and a service tech should make a visit to troubleshoot.

Comment: I also ran ping tests to cloudflare's DNS when I was gathering this test data, and it basically looks the same

Comment: The problem was indeed a bad line. Specifically, it was being caused by a filter they had placed on my line at the pole. They removed the filter and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The process I would follow includes

- `traceroute` from home to several somewheres outside the ISP's network (e.g. Google, Amazon, CNN, BBC), and take note of any intermediate IP addresses
- long-running `ping` tests to each of those IP addresses, with interspersed timestamps for later cross-referencing
- if there are any statistically-significant differences in the number of packets lost, then the corresponding differences in routes (verified by more `traceroute` output - remember, routes can change over time) are probably relevant

*Edit to add:*

If you don't already have a machine you can leave running to collect these logs, spend $100 on a Raspberry Pi (or similar) and a USB hard drive (and SD card and USB power supply and patch cable, if you don't already have them). You may also want a USB battery pack *that continues to supply current while charging* (which is not trivial to find), to use as a primitive UPS.

Run multiple `ping`+`date` logging sessions simultaneously, for several days at least. Be able to drown your ISP in data if you need to.

Comment: I don't know whether this service is available outside the UK, but ThinkBroadband have a quality tester, which is basically a full-time ping, with graphs - https://www.thinkbroadband.com/broadband/monitoring/quality/create [you may need to create an account to reach it, but it's free & pretty innocuous, not spammy.]

Comment: A datapoint, @Tetsujin: I was able to register and sign in from outside the UK, and create a monitor for an outside-UK IP address.